# Infopath 2010 terminate Workflow for current document

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath

Is it possible to create a button in an Infopath 2010 Document, so when the Documents Workflow is started the User is able to click on the Button to terminate the Workflow?

I actually have no idea on how to solve this right now, which is why I can't show what I have done so far. Either it's not that simple, or I'm just stupid as hell right now not figuring it out myself.

Thanks in advance